# React-Bootstrap: How to change the text of a selected eventKey

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

So I'm trying to figure out how to change some text on a selected dropdown button, but currently I have no idea on how to access it. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

```
return (
  <DropdownButton bsStyle={title.toLowerCase()} title={title} key={i} id={`dropdown-basic-${i}`}  onSelect={this.handleSelect}>
    <MenuItem eventKey="1">Some Text</MenuItem></DropdownButton>);
    ....


  handleSelect = (evt, evtKey) => {
if (evt == 1) { //EventKey 1 selected
  //Change the text

}
```

Comment: if you are storing the selected value in state then you can use the ternary oeprator to change the text like this: `<MenuItem eventKey="1">{this.state.value == 1 ? "Some Text": "Another Text"</MenuItem></DropdownButton>`

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the `state` then?

```
return (
  <DropdownButton bsStyle={title.toLowerCase()} title={title} key={i} id={`dropdown-basic-${i}`}  onSelect={this.handleSelect}>
    <MenuItem eventKey="1">{this.state.myText}</MenuItem></DropdownButton>);
    ....
```

Then in your handler:

```
 handleSelect = (evt, evtKey) => {
if (evt == 1) { //EventKey 1 selected
  //Change the text
  this.setState({myText : "text changed!"});
}
```